# ImportError: cannot import module - Only one module can not be imported from package

Tags: python

I created a package, for the ease of use I call it packageA.

In this package I have 4 submodules in (separate files) and an init file, so the package contains the following files:

- `__init__.py`
- moduleA.py
- moduleB.py
- moduleC.py
- moduleD.py

Module B-D stand alone, they don't import any other local module. Module A imports module B-D.

Now I have a script that wants to import `packageA`, the init.py is empty so far.

```
import packageA
```

works without problems. But moduleA is not available from this import. If I want to use it via packageA.moduleA it raises this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
```

The following also works without problems:

```
from packageA import moduleB
from packageA import moduleC
from packageA import moduleD
```

And the next import causes the ImportError:

```
from packageA import moduleA
```

raises this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 19, in <module>
from packageA import moduleA
ImportError: cannot import name moduleA
```

I thought that maybe I'm doing sth wrong in moduleA, but even if moduleA is empty the import raises the same error. It seems like that this module can't be imported somehow. How is this possible?

I have separete unit test files for all python modules, and yes, moduleA is working correctly without any errors.

Comment: if you are inside, package, you need to do `import packageB`

Comment: can you put proper order in which import is done and full traceback.

Comment: after importing packageA, are you able to use moduleA using packageA.moduleA

Comment: No, I can't use it,see my updated question. It raises an error that moduleA is unknown.

Comment: then i guess moduleA is not defined, moreover csn you post dummy code so that it can be clear, here your moduleA is function or a file, since init.py is file. I guess moduleA is also file. If not, in which file they are defined.

Comment: Yes, all modules are in separate files, and moduleA is working correctly - tested by an extra unit test file.

Comment: Is `init.py` really named so? Or did you omit `_` from `__init__.py` in the question text for some obscure reason?

Comment: Sorry, it always used the 2 underscores to bold the name, so I omitted them :) I corrected this above

Comment: no i mean you wrote packageA.moduleA is not working and even from is not working. can you share it on github or dummy code like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are importing a different version of the package from a different location. Try this in your script to make sure it is the right one -- it should print the full path of the `__init__.py` file.

```
import packageA
print packageA.__file__
```

Also, check if the package's module search path has been altered. Normally this is a list that contains one element, the directory path of the package:

```
print packageA.__path__
```

Comment: This raises an error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "run.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(packageA.__path__)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

But accessing moduleB via packageA.moduleB works fine

Comment: @raveN Try the edited answer. It sounds like packageA is a not a package, but a module that imports moduleB.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. It did not import my package, it imported a different package. The `__file__` pointed to an already installed version of my package, but it was a previous one without the missing module :/ Thanks a lot!

Comment: @raveN Additionally to accepting this answer, you could upvote it. :-)

Comment: @glglgl: No I can't, not enough reputation :)